# onItemClickListener crashes

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ArrayAdapter custom with AutocompleteTextView and onclicklistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511393/arrayadapter-custom-with-autocompletetextview-and-onclicklistener)

I'm struggling in understanding what's going on in my Android app wich uses a custom autocomplete class which works good. 
In particular I make a rest request, get the data, populate an ArrayList (I need some more infos), using filters and show a suggestions list (which is correct in according to server response). 
But, when I click on item, my app crashes. 
Suggestions??

here my adapter class:

```
package xxx;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AutoCompleteCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Intervento>  implements Filterable {

    static class ViewHolder{
         private TextView  textName;
    }

    private ArrayList<Intervento> arrayListIntervento;
    private int              layout;


    public ArrayList<Intervento> getArrayListIntervento() {
        return arrayListIntervento;
    }

    public void setArrayListIntervento(ArrayList<Intervento> arrayListIntervento) {
        this.arrayListIntervento = arrayListIntervento;
    }

    @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return arrayListIntervento.size();
      }

    @Override
    public Intervento getItem(int index) {
        return arrayListIntervento.get(index);
    }


     @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
         Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override


                protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        arrayListIntervento = (ArrayList<Intervento>)results.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence arg0) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if(arg0 != null) {
                        try {
                            arrayListIntervento = new InterventoController().execute("http://192.168.1.162:8080/.../InterventoHasSinonimoName/{interventohassinonimo_interventoNomeIntervento}/1/interventos", arg0.toString()).get();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                        filterResults.values = arrayListIntervento;
                        filterResults.count = arrayListIntervento.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }
            };
            return myFilter;
     }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View       view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(contentView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggest_list, viewGroup, false);

            if (view != null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeIntervento);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
                Intervento intervento = arrayListIntervento.get(position);
                if(intervento!=null){
                    viewHolder.textName.setText(intervento.getNome());
                }
            }
        }else {
            view = contentView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) contentView.getTag();
        }

        if (viewHolder != null) {
            Intervento intervento = arrayListIntervento.get(position);
            if(intervento!=null){
                viewHolder.textName.setText(intervento.getNome());
            }
        }

        return view;

    }

    public AutoCompleteCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        this.arrayListIntervento= new ArrayList<Intervento>();
        this.layout=textViewResourceId;
    }


}
```

And In my activity I call:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intervento intervento = ((Intervento) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                Integer idIntervento = intervento.getIdintervento();
                //autoCompleteTextView.setText(intervento);
            }
        });
```

here's the logcat:

```
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at it.stasbranger.clinigomobile.AutoCompleteCustomAdapter.getItem(AutoCompleteCustomAdapter.java:42)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at it.stasbranger.clinigomobile.AutoCompleteCustomAdapter.getItem(AutoCompleteCustomAdapter.java:1)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at it.stasbranger.clinigomobile.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:90)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:868)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1157)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-20 15:14:27.885: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: It's saying that the size of your array is 0.  You should step into the code where it's getting the item from the adapter and see why that is.

Comment: yes, naturally. Infact listView is a null array, even server response populate an array that's not null. 
It seem that in the passage from Custom Adapter class to Activity the array is get emptied.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cent worth:

arrayListIntervento seem to be empty:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

Maybe it is not populated correctly.
public void setArrayListIntervent maybye should do clone like:

```
public void setArrayListIntervento(ArrayList<Intervento> arrayListIntervento) {
    this.arrayListIntervento = arrayListIntervento.clone(); 
}
```

Comment: I added 
    public void setArrayListIntervento(ArrayList<Intervento>     arrayListIntervento) {
  this.arrayListIntervento = (ArrayList<Intervento>)     arrayListIntervento.clone(); 
  }

but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to remove `implements Filterable` from your class Adapter... because get Filter() method is just implemented into ArrayAdapter class.
How you have declared your AutoCompleteCustomAdapter into activity? Is a final declaration?

Comment: I corrected it but still not works!