# Adding an onClickListener event to a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom ArrayAdapter to display an array of tasks (around 12 of them) with a custom xml view. The adapter is passed strings from an activity, namely Title, Subject, Date and URL. 
The question i have is is there anyway to generate an onItemClickListener or any type of listener to 'holder.item1' shown below, in order to open up the string 'URL' in a webview, whilst **also passing http headers**?

My Class (TaskAdapter.java):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom>{
    private ArrayList<Custom> entries;
    private Activity activity;

    public TaskAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Custom> entries) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
        this.entries = entries;
        this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView item1;
        public TextView item2;
        public TextView item3;
        public TextView item4;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_tasks_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskLeft);
            holder.item4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textLink);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            holder.item1.setText(custom.getAssignment());
            holder.item4.setText(custom.itemLink());
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

My XML (activity_task_adapter.xml):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskLeft"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Left"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#eedbde"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLink"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Left"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#eedbde"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>          

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried using setOnClickListener on the item1 but that didnt work, and the only thing i could find similar to this on SO was the following:

[ArrayAdapter custom with AutocompleteTextView and onclicklistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511393/arrayadapter-custom-with-autocompletetextview-and-onclicklistener)

Comment: Did you made your TextView clickable=true in xml when you set the click listener on it?

Comment: I did, but this neither loaded the link or let me set the headers (a key and a token). I tried android:autoLink="web" with the TextView and that loaded the page in a browser, but the key and the token were not in the http headers so therefore the authentication failed.